# How to use Cramer's rule for $AX=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For a general system of equation $AX=b$, Cramer's rule states to obtain $x_j$, we need to replace the $j$th column of $A$ with $b$, let us name this matrix as $D_j$ then calculate

$$
\dfrac{\det(D_j)}{\det(A)}
$$

How ever if $b=0$, it always returns the trivial solution $0$ because the numerator will be determinant of a matrix whose  $j$th column is zero. I would like to know how to solve the system by Cramer rule for $AX=0$?

Comment: if $A$ is an invertible square matrix and $x$ is a vector then $Ax=0$ if and only if $x=0$

Comment: @Masacroso If so, then the eigenpair equation $AX=\lambda X$ always returns eigenvector $X=0$.

Comment: @MamaD The eigenpair equation is $(A-\lambda I_n)X = 0$, which has nonzero solutions precisely when $A-\lambda I_n$ is non invertible. You can't use Cramer's rule to find a solution.
In fact, you don't have a general algorithm to solve this problem: it would be equivalent to finding the roots of any polynomial.

Comment: @Didier as a result I shouldn't use Cramer when $b=0$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cramer's rule is useful to solve the linear system $Ax=b$ only if $\text{det}(A)\neq 0$. When $\text{det}(A)\neq 0$ the homogeneous linear system $Ax=0$ has only the zero solution $x=0$. Notice that if the square matrix $A$ is invertible, one has
$$Ax=0 \iff A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}0 \iff Ix=0 \iff x=0$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, then the eigenpair equation $AX=\lambda X$ or $(A - \lambda I) X=0$ would always return eigenvector $X=0$ as solution while zero vector isnot an eigenvector

Comment: An eigenvector is by definition the NONZERO vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ for some number $\lambda$. To find an eigenvector we look for the number $\lambda$ such that the homogeneous linear system $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ has a NONZERO solution. Such $\lambda$ must obey the characteristic equation $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: What if there is atleast one free variable? can I still use Cramer's rule?